# Azure Stack Exchange Redis setting a key 2nd time should fail

Tags: redis, locking, stackexchange.redis

I'm using StackExchange.Redis IDatabase.StringSetAsync in an event subscriber to deduplicate events **and I want this operation to fail if the key used all ready exist.**
I do check if the key exist. But I want to make sure a race condition where two subscriber instances both read at the same time and find that no key exist and then both try to set the key.

I have read about "watch" in Redis. But this concept seems to be abstracted away in StackExchange.Redis implementation.